# Apache HTACCESS directory/wrong php code?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I run an Apache server on my network for my movies. I recently discovered the power of .HTACCESS and decided I'd try use it to make all my directories look nice instead of the default index. Problem is that I use a basic PHP script which gets only the currently directory, and not from inside all the movie directories like I want. The reason I'm doing this is so I don't have to copy/paste an index file into every single of my 540 folders. I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong or some different PHP I could use. Any help appreciated.

This is my .HTACCESS

```
# DISABLE DIRECTORY VIEWS
Options +Indexes

# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# DIRECTORY CUSTOMIZATION
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>

</IfModule>

# SET INDEX OPTIONS
IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=70    DescriptionWidth=* VersionSort SuppressHTMLPreamble IconWidth=40 SuppressDescription SuppressLastModified SuppressSize HTMLTable 

# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName /header.php

# SPECIFY FOOTER FILE
ReadmeName /footer.html

# IGNORE THESE FILES
IndexIgnore header.html index.php *.nfo *.txt *.srt footer.html favicon.ico .htaccess .ftpquota .DS_Store icons *.log *,v *,t .??* *~ *# Thumbs.db

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php

  // open this directory 
  $myDirectory = opendir(".");

  // get each entry
  while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
          $dirArray[] = $entryName;
  }

  // close directory
  closedir($myDirectory);

  //      count elements in array
  $indexCount     = count($dirArray);

  // sort 'em
  sort($dirArray);

  // print 'em

  print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0 class='main'>");
  Print ("<td><b>$indexCount movies</b></td>");

  //print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH></TR>\n");

  // loop through the array of files and print them all
  for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
          if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){// don't list hidden files
                  print("<TR><TD width='50%'><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
                  print("</TR>\n");
          }
          }
  print("</TABLE>\n");
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recoursive directory reader class:

```
class DirectoryReader {

      public static function readFolderRecursive($folder, &$res) {
          if(substr($folder,-1) == "/") {
              $folder = substr($folder,0,-1);
          }
          $data = self::readFolder($folder);
          foreach($data['files'] as $k => $f) {
              $res[] = array('type'=>'file','path'=>$folder."/".$f, 'filename'=>$f);
          }
          foreach($data['folder'] as $k => $f) {
              $tmp = $folder."/".$f;
              $res[] = array('type'=>'folder','path'=>$folder."/".$f);
              self::readFolderRecursive($tmp, $res);
          }
      }

      public static function readFolder($folder) {
          $files = array();
          $folders = array();

          if(is_dir($folder) ) {
              if(substr($folder,-1) == "/") {
                  $folder = substr($folder,0,-1);
              }
              $handle = opendir($folder);
              while ($file = readdir ($handle)) {
                  if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                      if(is_dir($folder."/".$file)) {
                          $folders[] = $file;
                      } else {
                          $files[]= $file;
                      }
                  }
              }
              closedir($handle);
          }
          return array("folder" => $folders, "files" => $files);
      }

}

$data = array();
DirectoryReader::readFolderRecursive(".",$data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

It reads all subfolder and files of a given folder into an array. You should be able to format the resulting $data array by yourself.

So you are able to produce a single page where you can see all contents of all subfolders. You don't need to reload the php-file if you want open another directory. You can resolve this with pure javascript.

An example result will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => ./test.php
            [filename] => test.php
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [path] => ./example_folder_2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => ./example_folder_2/file3.txt
            [filename] => file3.txt
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [path] => ./example_folder_1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => ./example_folder_1/file1.txt
            [filename] => file1.txt
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [path] => ./example_folder_1/example_subfolder
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => ./example_folder_1/example_subfolder/file2.txt
            [filename] => file2.txt
        )

)
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm noob but I got rid of the PHP and added
    <script src="script.js"></script>
in the body and the script isnt loading

Comment: I figured it out but I'm getting an error that it can't find the class. Fatal error: Class 'DirectoryReader' not found in *my php file*. I tried putting the class in the php file and putting it in its own .js and using script src but still same error.

Comment: I got the script working, what do I do now! It's displaying every file in every directory. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It depends on what you like to show the viewer. The easiest is to show every file like you did in your version. But if you have so many files it would be a little bit overkilling. I think it would be nice to create a filebrowser with javascript. But this is not trivial. Sorry i have not the time now to continue. It should be just a hint how it could be realized.

Comment: I see i confused you with my Javascript hint. The posted code is only php. You may prepare the data in json to be able to create a fileviewer with js. Thats what i ment.